# 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the code in question:

```
arr = ['-0.944', '0.472', '0.472']
charges = [np.float64(i) for i in arr] # [-0.944, 0.472, 0.472]
charges = np.ndarray(charges)
```

The error is thrown on the last step, where the list is casted to an ndarray. Assigning `dtype=np.float64` in ndarray does not change the error. What is wrong with this snippet of code?

Numpy 1.14,
Python 3.6.1

Comment: The constructor you're looking for is `array`, not `ndarray`. Calling `ndarray` directly is unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `np.ndarray` is the `shape`, which is usually a tuple of integers.

You should not use the low-level constructor `np.ndarray`.  Correct interface is `np.array`, and take it directly from the strings without a list comprehension first:

```
>>> arr = ['-0.944', '0.472', '0.472']
>>> np.array(arr, dtype=np.float64)
array([-0.944,  0.472,  0.472])
```

Comment: Thanks -- rookie mistake!